# I want to remove the timed aspect of this crowdsale contract and make it finalizable manually

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, tokens, crowdsale

Which lines do I remove and what do I replace them with to change this from a timed crowdsale contract into one I can end manually?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) external;
}

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public deadline;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    /**
     * Constructor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) public {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function () payable public {
        require(!crowdsaleClosed);
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
       emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /**
     * Check if goal was reached
     *
     * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
     */
    function checkGoalReached() public afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            emit GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    /**
     * Withdraw the funds
     *
     * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
     * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
     * the amount they contributed.
     */
    function safeWithdrawal() public afterDeadline {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                   emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
               emit FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What about the contract do you understand / confuses you?

Comment: I tried removing everything that was related to funding goals, time starts etc. but then it didn't work so I am obviously removing too much or not enough and that is where I get lost.

Comment: Then what did you add to enable "manual finalization"? Have you looked at open source crowd-sale contracts like [openzeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale)?

Comment: I didn't because after removing the stuff mentioned above it wouldn't work so I didn't even attempt it. I have looked at openzeppelin contracts but again haven't found one that has a manual finalization feature, at least not that I could see. Thanks for your help and if you have any other suggestions I would appreciate them.

Comment: I think your question is not very specific. Your smart contract is not trivial and you request to remove a feature is complicated. A good answer will imply an almost total rewrite of your contract.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply remove every instance of the `afterDeadline` modifier and the contract will no longer rely on any timing function.

I advise you to learn more about the contract and perhaps rewrite it to follow best practices. Take a look at the [OpenZeppelin crowdsale contracts](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity).